# How do I find the height of the centre of a hypotenuse of an inclined right angle triangle?

Tags: geometry

[image]As shown in the diagram, I have a triangle $ABC$ which is inclined at an angle of $60^{\circ}$ above a plane "the ground" on side $AC$ and $30^{\circ}$ on side $CB$. The triangle is a right angle triangle: $\angle ACB = 90^{\circ}$ and $\angle CAB$ = $\theta$. $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$ (the centre of the hypotenuse), $AB$ has length $L$, and I would like to find the height $h$ of $M$ above the ground in terms of $α$ and the length $L$.

[[Here is the diagram showing what has been described above]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MpUi.jpg)

Edit: the original diagram contained an error (M was mislabelled as C). This has been corrected

Answer (score 1):

Drop perpendiculars from $A$ and $B$ to the ground, and let the lengths of the perpendiculars be $x$ and $y$. Then clearly $h = \frac{x+y}{2}$.

Now, letting $b$ be the length of $AC$ and $a$ the length of $BC$, we have
$$b = L\cos\theta,\quad a = L\sin\theta$$
and
$$ x = b\sin 60^{\circ},\quad y = a\sin 30^{\circ} = a\cos 60^{\circ},$$
so that
$$x+y = L\cos\theta\sin 60^{\circ} + L\sin\theta\cos 60^{\circ}
= L\sin(\theta +60^{\circ}).$$
Then
$$ h = \frac{x+y}{2} = \frac{L}{2}\sin(\theta + 60^{\circ}).$$

Comment: ty this helped. However, for the sake of clarity could you please change the variable name from "c" to "h" at the end as you used "h" at the beginning and that is what I used in the original post

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Draw $AM$

$AM=BM=CM=\frac{L}{2}$

and $\angle AMD=\theta-30$

$$\cos (\theta-30)=\frac {h}{\frac{L}{2}}$$

$$h=\frac {L}{2}\times{\cos (\theta-30)}=\frac {L}{2}\times{\cos (30 -\theta)}$$

Since, ${\cos (\theta-30)}=\cos (30 -\theta)$